# Cordova blocks AJAX call to file:// URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, iframe

I have a Cordova app which should run a 3rd-party library within an iframe. The iframe cannot be omitted since it would brake the layout of the app. The library, within the iframe, then tries to load some JSON files via AJAX using jQuery from the local file system, e.g. file://some/path/translations.json. But the request gets blocked causing the errors `Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.` and `Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`.

I've already set the following Cordova options and I'm running out of ideas on how to fix this.

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="file://*/*" />
```

Did anyone run into the same issue? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the issue was. I'm using the wkwebview-enginge plugin. WKWebView currently blocks AJAX calls to file:// URLs. To overcome this I had to use the [local-webserver plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/local-webserver) to serve the application locally over HTTP. This is a long standing issue and it's note something the Cordova team can solve themselves. So, lets hope Apple brings some improvements here with iOS 10.